# how to call methods of excanvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, excanvas, rgraph

I need a little help from you. I have created a canvas image using [excanvas.js](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) and it was rendered properly. Now i want to use that same canvas to draw another image but before that i need to clear that same canvas otherwise images will be overlapped over each other.
Can anyone please explain how can i call [fillRect()](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) or any another method from [excanvas.js](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) for the same canvas element ?? I am using IE 8 as browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, excanvas.width, excanvas.height);
```

or perhaps:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff"; 
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, excanvas.width, excanvas.height);
```

Where `excanvas` is your DOMElement canvas, and `ctx` being its 2d context (via `getContext('2d')`).